# Populating ListView in MonoDroid: Custom ArrayAdapter or Custom ListAdapter?

Tags: listview, dynamic, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have a ListView, with each element containing several TextViews. I need to populate this ListView dynamically. After a bit of research, it appears I must do this either with a custom ArrayAdapter or a custom ListAdapter.

Are my choices limited to these two, or is there a better technique?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Adapter by creating an class deriving from : BaseAdapter.
Then you can use the GetView function to Inflate - for instance - a resource layout file with a Linearlayout as root and textviews, images, etc as child elements.

[This page](http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview) helped me a lot in learning the concept of custom elements/adapters.